# Combine two Images into one new Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

I have two JPEG files with different dimensions:

Image1 (Width1,Height1)

Image2 (Width2,Height2)

I want to create Image3 (Width3, Height3) with Image1 on the left side and Image2 on the right.

Answer (score 57):

Something like this will give you a new image with the two original images side by side.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1.Width + image2.Width, Math.Max(image1.Height, image2.Height));
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);
    g.DrawImage(image2, image1.Width, 0);
}
```

Comment: is the result of the .DrawImage() calls stored in the bitmap object?

Comment: Correct ... g is the graphics context of bitmap.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem.
With this function you can merge multiple Bitmap's into a single image

```
    private Bitmap MergeImages(IEnumerable<Bitmap> images)
    {
        var enumerable = images as IList<Bitmap> ?? images.ToList();

        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        foreach (var image in enumerable)
        {
            width += image.Width;
            height = image.Height > height
                ? image.Height
                : height;
        }

        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            var localWidth = 0;
            foreach (var image in enumerable)
            {
                g.DrawImage(image, localWidth, 0);
                localWidth += image.Width;
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **You can try it**
>
> library you need using

`using System.Drawing;
 using System.Drawing.Imaging;
 //controller`

```
public ActionResult Image()     
    {
        var bitmap = GetBitmap(); // The method that returns List<Bitmap>
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        foreach (var image in bitmap)
        {
            width += image.Width;
            height = image.Height > height
                ? image.Height
                : height;
        }
        var bitmap2 = new Bitmap(width, height);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2);
        var localWidth = 0;
        foreach (var image in bitmap)
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, localWidth, 0);
            localWidth += image.Width;
        }

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        bitmap2.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
         var   result = ms.ToArray();
         //string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(result); 
         return File(result, "image/jpeg"); //Return as file result
        //return base64String;
    }
//this method returns List<Bitmap>
public List<Bitmap> GetBitmap()
    {
        var lstbitmap = new List<Bitmap>();
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(@"E:\My project\ProjectImage\ProjectImage\BmImage\1525244892128.JPEG");
        var bitmap2 = new Bitmap(@"E:\My project\ProjectImage\ProjectImage\BmImage\1525244892204.JPEG");
        var bitmap3 = new Bitmap(@"E:\My project\ProjectImage\ProjectImage\BmImage\3.jpg");
        lstbitmap.Add(bitmap);
        lstbitmap.Add(bitmap2);
        lstbitmap.Add(bitmap3);
        return lstbitmap;
    }
```

> **Good luck!**