# How can I join two images one above another

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine two Images into one new Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206510/combine-two-images-into-one-new-image)

I have a c# code that creates 2 images; now I want to join them by placing first image above the second image?

This is what I have done so far:

```
        var myBitmap = new Bitmap(longestLine * 40, 40);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        var strFormat = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        g.DrawString(FirstLine, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 40), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, longestLine * 40, totalLines * 40), strFormat);

        var myBitmap2 = new Bitmap(longestLine * 40, 40);
        var g2 = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap2);
        g2.Clear(Color.White);
        var strFormat2 = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        g2.DrawString(SecondLine, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 40), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, longestLine * 40, totalLines * 40), strFormat);
```

Comment: You might start here to figure out how to combine two side by side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206510/combine-two-images-into-one-new-image

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm! Answer and I will pick it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Combine two Images into one new Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206510/combine-two-images-into-one-new-image) was used for adding two bitmaps side by side. I've used it myself, and it seems to work just fine.